# Problems with Compiling sml-mode in emacs

Tags: emacs, sml

I'm trying to install sml-mode via package manager in emacs but it won't compile correctly.
Here's the log:

```
Compiling no file at Sun Oct 11 18:34:14 2015
Leaving directory `/Users/a/.emacs.d/elpa/sml-mode-6.7'

Compiling file /Users/a/.emacs.d/elpa/sml-mode-6.7/sml-mode-pkg.el at Sun Oct 11 18:34:14 2015
Entering directory `/Users/a/.emacs.d/elpa/sml-mode-6.7/'

Compiling file /Users/a/.emacs.d/elpa/sml-mode-6.7/sml-mode.el at Sun Oct 11 18:34:14 2015
sml-mode.el:494:1:Warning: Unused lexical variable `data'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: When byte-compiling, there will generally be some warnings -- that doesn't necessarily mean that the installation via package manager failed.

Comment: You are right. Thank you.